# Create an array in query Knex

Tags: mysql, knex.js

So what I am trying to do is query for a list of items and group them based on their group Ids. I am new to mySQL, and I would like to know two things:

1. How you would create a new property to store this array
2. How would you grab these items in such a way that you can put them in said array

I am joining two tables together and it is resulting in something like the following:

```
{
  itemId1,
  itemId2,
  itemName,
  groupId,
  groupName
}
```

What I want to do is make it look like the following:

```
{
  groupName,
  groupId,
  itemArray:[{ itemId1, itemName }]
}
```

Is what I am doing even possible with just using knex alone?

Edit: I don't necessarily need a solution, but just some advice that would point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out how to do it. For those who may come across a similar problem, I found using `JSON_ARRAYAGG`, `json_object`, and `groupBy` as good tools to use when creating the data structure that I was trying to query for. When using **JSON_ARRAYAGG  and json_object**, you will need to use `knex`.raw because I don't think knex has those two functions.